# MongoDb Spring data GeoNear query with max and min distance

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to implement `$near query` in spring data mongodb with `maxDistance` and `minDistance`. `NearQuery` has `maxDistance` but doesn't have `minDistance`. According to [mongodb explanation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#examples) it support `minDistance` with `maxDistance`. I could not find any sample code doing this in spring and could not see that in soring data mongodb api in spring.
Furthermore, [This doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#nearsphere) is also doing what I need and I dont know how to impelement `$nearSphere` in spring.

```
 Point point = new Point(longitude, latitude);
 NearQuery nq = NearQuery.near(point).maxDistance(new Distance(2, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not supported yet. I've filed [DATAMONGO-1110](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1110) for you.

Comment: for my last 2 question , I am disappointed about spring data mongodb :) I would expect that spring cover all mongodb functionality. how much time do you think it will take to have minDistance support in near query in spring? I am really in a hurry for my project. Advice me something.

Comment: If you're in a hurry I can advice to clone the [repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb), implement the feature and create a pull request. That will increase the likelihood the ticket will make it into the next release. :)

Comment: I am also looking for this feature. If I understand well, this is not yet implemented in mongoDB-spring, but implemented in mongoDB? Do you know if this works in mongodB + nodeJs ?

Comment: @OliverGierke just a notification. as I know , there other people waiting for this feature. i tried to  modify your repo by myself, but it was abit hard for me and i really don't have much time to work on it for implementing this feature.

Comment: If you'd like to raise the importance of the issue it's best to just vote for the ticket to be solved as the number of votes influences when the issue will be approached.

Comment: @nha can you do what is told us.

Comment: @Emilla not sure what you mean. Are you asking if I can do the pull request (I probably won't) ?

Comment: @nha please read that [If you'd like to raise the importance of the issue it's best to just vote for the ticket to be solved as the number of votes influences when the issue will be approached]

Comment: @Emilla ok [filling character count]

Comment: @OliverGierke, sorry for my stupid question. when will your new release be seen in maven repository? im using mongdb spring data by maven dependency.

Comment: How we can work with two Indexes named as "$nearSphere" and $TextSearch? Please help me I see following error:
"errmsg" : "text and geoNear not allowed in same query" , "code" : 2